# get gear s3 data through artik cloud

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, samsung-galaxy, samsung-galaxy-gear

I connected my gear s3 watch to Samsung's artik cloud and Im getting heart rate data. Is there any way I can get data such as acceleration etc.
for example by creating an application on Tizen Studio that will send these data to the artik cloud?

Comment: Please share your source code of fetching heart rate data from ARTIK cloud.

Comment: hello! you don't a source code to fetch heart rate data. ARTIK cloud already does just by connecting the watch to your artik account. This is why I'm asking if it is possible to fetch data (for example accelaration) other than the heart rate?